# Default login after logout

Tags: login-screen, logout

I can set the default login that's used when I first start my system -- in fact, the installation procedure specifically allows for setting the startup to log in automatically.  But is there a way to get that automatic login to be used after logout?

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10.

Comment: What would be the point of logging out then?

Comment: @aroll605: There would be a ton of nifty things you could do with that: E.g. In Kiosk more, if the user session gets stuck, you do a remote log off and then it logs back on automatically and it's working again! (**Excellent question!** Upvoted and made a favourite as I'd be interested in an answer as well!!)

Comment: user101815: I would change the title to "Log back on automatically after log off" though... (but it's *your* question)  Drop me a note @Fabby to discuss or drop by in the chat in the General Room!

Comment: Sometimes you might want to log back in as a different user, or specify some other login option.  The neat way to handle this would be to fill in the password field with bullets, so that just pressing Enter would do the actual login.

Comment: At one time it was possible to specify auto-login on a per-user basis, but that option doesn't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 3):

open  file:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-kubuntu.conf
```

and change line user-session to what session you want to set it as default session (default is `kde-plasma.desktop` for kubuntu 14.10)

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=kde-plasma.desktop
```

You can get all installed session on your Kubuntu with the following command:

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/

gnome.desktop
kde-plasma.desktop
ubuntu.desktop
xfce.desktop
xubuntu.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Found something!

In the `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` documentation I found the following parameters in the `[SeatDefaults]` section:

```
# autologin-user = User to log in with by default (overrides autologin-guest)
# autologin-user-timeout = Number of seconds to wait before loading default user
```

:-)

`/etc/init/lightdm.conf` is a dud: it's some script that starts lightdm...

However in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` are a bunch of scripts that contain the section [SeatDefaults] of which `50-unity-greeter.conf` contains a modification by myself to turn on the numlock on login, so I'm convinced that that is where we should start looking...

This isn't a real "answer" to your question but more an invite to work together on how to solve this...  **your thoughts?**

P.S. Your reputation is high enough to just [edit] my answer and change it the way you want...